# Oracle SQL Developer doesn't start

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've tried everything on this site, but I can't seem to start SQL Developer properly. I am using Oracle express edition and windows 7. My SQL Developer version is 4.1.3 and JDK version is jdk1.8.0_101.

It gets stuck on here and doesn't start:

[image]

I tried moving SQL Developer to different folders. I tried installing different versions. I tried everything on this site but nothing solves my problem or when something works it is temporary and next time I open it, it is stuck again.

Please help, and moderators please don't close my question because nothing on here works for me!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the SQL language. Don't add that tag one more time!

Comment: *when something works it is temporary*.. Can you expand on that?  What works exactly? How long does it keep working for?  When it does work, is it as a result of something you did, or is it random?  When it fails to work, does the progress bar always get stuck at the exact same spot as seen in your screenshot?

Comment: i edited it out ! maybe it didn't have anything to do with the language but my problem is with "SQL" Developer i added it to reach more people in that tag. Don't worry i removed it!

Comment: @sstan It sometimes works when i restart my computer but not every time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to your AppData folder under your Windows OS User's home directory.

Under there is a roaming profiles directory, and under that there should be a SQL Developer folder.

In THERE, you'll see a systemW.X.Y.Z... folder - rename that.

This stores the application settings, including things like your connections for a specific version of SQL Developer.

Try starting SQL Developer again.

You can go back into your renamed folder to recover things as needed if starting fresh fixes the issue.

Comment: Helped me, I was using sqldeveloper in VM so had tried so many things like using it in different drive and editing the jdk.conf and ide.conf to increase the "AddVMOption size and jdk" they were not my issues, it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

I faced this issue on **Windows 10** system and **Oracle SQL Developer v 18.1**

> Start -> Run -> %AppData%\SQL Developer\

It will open a folder in explorer. Delete this folder.

Now restart the SQL Developer. It will ask if you would like to import existing profile? Select 'No' and click Next.

SQL developer worked properly after that.

Answer (score 1):

close all sql developer instances
go in the directory %AppData%\SQL Developer\system..... rename all the files system_cache..
now start sql developer

Answer (score 0):

In my case to run SQL Developer - needed to place SQL Developer folder to disk C:\ but not disk D:\

Answer (score 0):

If the ide does not open after loading in, it could be that some settings files in `/App Data/Roaming/SQL Developer/system<version#>` were corrupted. The safest file to delete would be `o.ide.<version#>/oracledbtoolsraptorstartpageStartPage.html`.

Running the app again will regenerate this file and should hopefully allow it to launch to welcome page again.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, it got further than me, but the root cause of it not opening for me could theoretically cause some of the same issues you're encountering.  In my case, I had a partial directory extraction from the SQL Developer zip file that caused it to fail to open.

In my particular case, it wouldn't even show a splash screen and also happened when using the embedded JDK.  The essence of this answer is making sure all files have been extracted properly.  It's simple but ended up being the issue in my case.  I hope that helps someone out there.